# Using jbuilder to access child objects in has many relationship

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

Trying to use jbuilder with gon gem to pass an object and its child objects to javascript, where object is a `lender` and it has many children, which are `inventories`. Following instructions from gon gem [here](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-with-jbuilder), but I'm maintaining that this is a question on the jbuilder side, not gon... you'll see why.

Current code to fetch lenders:

**#/test.json.builder**

```
json.lenders @lenders, :email, :latitude, :longitude
```

**Test Action in Controller code**

```
@lenders = Signups.all
gon.jbuilder
```

**#/test.html.erb**

```
<script>
  console.log(gon.lenders)
</script>
```

This is working fine, and produces the following output:[image]

However, when I try to fetch the children `inventories` using standard jbuilder code per Ryan Bates' show [notes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder), like so:

**#/test.json.builder**

```
json.lenders @lenders, :email, :latitude, :longitude
json.inventories @lenders.inventories, :id, :itemlist_id, :description
```

I get the error: `undefined method`inventories' for #`

**I get why I'm getting the error, because per output above, the result of `@lenders` is an array of the `lenders`, not the lender objects themselves, but then how else do I get the inventories?** My desired goal is that the output looks as above, but that for each object, there is an `inventories` field which produces an array of the individual `inventory` objects, each with the attributes `id`, `itemlist_id` and `description`.

---

Things I've tried that have produced same error:

**ONE** other variation of getting to child per Ryan Bates

```
json.comments @article.comments do |json, comment|
  json.partial! comment
end

#in partial
  json.(comment, :id, :name, :content)
```

**TWO** including inventories in controller code

**Test Action in Controller code**

```
@lenders = Signups.all.includes(:inventories)
gon.jbuilder
```

And this is not a gon problem, gon is installed after jbuilder in gemfile, and I am including it in the view header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this worked:

**#/test.json.builder**

```
json.array!(@lenders) do |json, lender|
  json.(lender, :id, :email, :latitude, :longitude)
  json.inventories lender.inventories do |json, inventory|
    json.(inventory, :id, :itemlist_id, :description)
  end
end
```

Drawn from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959757/generate-an-nested-json-array-in-jbuilder)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to nest `has many` relationships.

```
json.array! @votations do |votation|
  json.id votation.id
  json.description votation.description
  json.status votation.status
  json.name votation.name
  json.options do
    json.array! votation.options, :id, :name, :votation_id
  end
end
```