# How can i map one query result to another query result in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am new to Ruby on Rails development. I have two queries with different model.  My first_query is get from question model and second query is get from favourite model. I want to map with a column user_favourite from  second query result to first query result.

this is my controller queries

```
def index
    @first_query = Question.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per( (ENV['ILM_QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE'] || 5).to_i )
    @second_query=Favourite.with_user_favourite(@user)
    @combined_queries = @first_query + @second_query
end
```

favourite.rb

```
scope :with_user_favourite, -> (user) {
    joins(:user).
    where(favourites: {user_id: user})
  }
```

index.json.builder

```
json.questions @combined_events
```

json for the result is

```
{
questions: [      #this is first query result
        {
            id: 88,
            user_id: 28,
            content: "test32",
            image: {
            url: null,
            thumb: {
                url: null
            },
            mobile: {
                url: null
            }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 87,
            user_id: 18,
            content: "testing riyas",
            image: {
            url: null,
            thumb: {
                url: null
            },
            mobile: {
                url: null
            }
            }
        },
        {              #this is second query result
            id: 1,
            user_id: 2,
            question_id: 84,
            created_at: "2016-05-12T06:51:54.555-04:00",
            updated_at: "2016-05-12T06:51:54.555-04:00"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            user_id: 2,
            question_id: 81,
            created_at: "2016-05-12T07:23:47.770-04:00",
            updated_at: "2016-05-12T07:23:47.770-04:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

i want response like

```
{
questions: [      
        {                            #first query result
            id: 88, 
            user_id: 28,
            content: "test32",
            image: {
            url: null,
            thumb: {
                url: null
            },
            mobile: {
                url: null
            }
            },
            user_favorite: {       #corresponding result from second query result
                id: 1,
                user_id: 2,
                question_id: 88
            }
        },
        {                           #first query result
            id: 87,
            user_id: 18,
            content: "testing riyas",
            image: {
            url: null,
            thumb: {
                url: null
            },
            mobile: {
                url: null
            }
            },
            user_favorite: {}       #corresponding result from second query result if there is no result for particular question in favourite table
        },
    ]
}
```

The model relationships are:

```
class Question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favourite
end

class Favourite
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end

class User
  has_many :questions
  has_many :favourite
end
```

Comment: What is the relation between Question model, Favorite model and User model?

Comment: Add  your associations

Comment: in question.rb 

belongs_to :user
has_many :favourite

in favourite.rb

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :question

in user.rb

has_many :questions
has_many :favourite

Comment: You're either using rails 3 or rails 4 - not both. Run `rails --version` - what version are you using?

Comment: @Riyaskhan You can use the `edit` button below the Question (directly above these comments) to add new information to your question.  Please do this, instead of pasting code into comments.  I've placed your model relationships in the question, and you should do the same with any additional information that you include.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your jBuilder template to support nesting.Since your model association is like one question has_many favorite so it will be an array and you can easily nest one object inside another.

```
 json.array! @questions do |question| 
    json.user_id question.user_id
    json.content question.content
    json.user_favorites question.favorites do |json,favorite|
       json.id question.favorite.id
       json.user_id question.favorite.user.id
       json.question_id question.id
    end 
end
```

Here is a link that you can refer to for more clarity.

[Generate a nested JSON array in JBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959757/generate-an-nested-json-array-in-jbuilder)

[Using JBuilder to create nested JSON output in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084117/using-jbuilder-to-create-nested-json-output-in-rails)

Hope it helps!.

Comment: i got this error .undefined method `favorites' for #<Question:0x000000067ffca0>

Comment: As you said in question.rb  Model you have following association "has_many" :favourite. It should not show that error.@ Riyas can you please post the association? May be it can help us to find if cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an association between `user_favourite` and `question` so that you can select all user favourites on one question.

Question.rb:

```
has_many :user_favourites
```

UserFavourite.rb:

```
belongs_to :question
```

Then, as your web action:

```
def index
  @questions = Question.all.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per((ENV['ILM_QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE'] || 5).to_i)
end
```

And finally, in index.json.builder:

```
json.questions @questions do |question|
  json.user_favourites question.user_favourites
end
```

including whatever other fields you want.